# WPF position specific tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, tooltip

I have a Canvas that contains lots of DrawingVisuals (i.e. not FrameworkElements) and I'd like to present a tooltip as the mouse hovers over a given DrawingVisual. Not quite sure how to achieve this since a tooltip seems to be tied to a FrameworkElement.

I guess I need some way to assign 'tooltip hotspots' within a single FrameworkElement.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e761b78-14d6-4e06-adcc-43a847844c58/how-can-i-add-a-tool-tip-to-a-visual-element?forum=wpf

Comment: Thanks David, I didn't realise I could just create a tooltip and 'open it'. I can do what I need now.